# STUFF function not retrieving correct results in Production DB

Tags: sql-server-2017-express

I have the below query working in my local db but not in production. Could anyone please help me out:

```
declare @abc varchar(max)
set @abc = (select distinct stuff((select ',' + emp_id from TableA FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1, '') From TableA
print @abc
```

The result set locally is:

```
abc
123,432,6789,2345
```

But in production:

```
abc
----- results only with commas and 1's.
```

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but do you have the same data in prod as locally?

Comment: got it. I have empty data in the first few rows. After doing distinct inside the select statement, it works